# Pyspark Incremental Load from Source to Target bucket to handle update and add records as in SCD1 without full read of source and target?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have source data in s3 bucket in csv files with a column 'merchant_id' which is unique and 'action' with possible values 'A' for add and 'U' for update. The first input file was only with A values. I designed a pipeline to copy source files into target bucket and save it in parquet format. Every week I have delta files (new records) coming into my source bucket. I want to records with 'A' values in action column in the new files to target bucket and I wan't to replace records in target bucket with same merchant_id  that are now updated ie. merchant_id's with  'U' values in action column in new files. What is the best approach to do that in pyspark considering I don't want to read full data from source and target everytime. I wan't to do it incrementally so that only new records are inserted and replaced

My approach for now is to fully read the source data and select the most recent records by using file_date column (much like partition by merchant_id order by date desc and then select rank 1 ) and overwrite the target folder.